# How to set both spacing between characters (kern) and strikethrough style for `UILabel`?

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, swift4, nsattributedstring

I need to set two attributes to a text presented by a `UILabel`: spacing between letters (kern), and its strikethrough style. Based on the `NSAttributedStringKey` documentation I have created the following extension to the `UILabel`:

```
extension UILabel {
    func setStrikeThroughSpacedText(text: String, kern: CGFloat?) {
        var attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey : Any] = [:]
        if let kern = kern {
            attributes[.kern] = kern
        }
        attributes[.strikethroughStyle] 
                  = NSNumber(integerLiteral: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue)
        self.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: text,
                                                 attributes: attributes)
    }
}
```

However, it seems that `.kern` key somehow collides with the `.strikethroughStyle` key, because if I specify kern, the kern is applied, but not the strikethrough style. If I don't specify kern (so the extension does not apply the `.kern` attribute), the strikethrough style works.

Anyone has a different way how to work around this bug (I assume this is a bug)?

Comment: This, indeed, seems like a bug. Did you file a radar?

Comment: not yet.. although I just tested it in simulator on iOS 11 and it seems to be working there.. so it seems that they fixed it there..

Comment: See an updated answer with result.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this, it should work for you 

Note: I tested in **Swift 4**

```
let label = UILabel()
let stringValue = "How to\ncontrol\nthe\nline spacing\nin UILabel"
let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: stringValue)
let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
style.lineSpacing = 24 // change line spacing between paragraph like 36 or 48
style.minimumLineHeight = 20 // change line spacing between each line like 30 or 40
attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle, value: style, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: stringValue.count))
attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.strikethroughStyle, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.kern, value: 2, range: NSMakeRange(0, attrString.length))
label.attributedText = attrString
```

**Result:**

Sim 1: Strike +  LineSpacing

Sim 2: Strike +  LineSpacing + Character Spacing

[image]

Comment: `.kern` attribute sets character spacing, not line spacing

Comment: Try with Xcode 9 (Swift 4) and iOS 10 simulator. (You may be using Xcode 8 with Swift 3)

Comment: im using XCode 9 beta, swift 4, and iOS 10 device

Comment: But ill accept your answer, it's not really so crucial for me to run it on iOS 10, if it's working correctly on iOS 11