# Wrong height for UILabel when using custom lineSpacing and kern

Tags: ios, uikit, uilabel, nsattributedstring, kerning

I am getting wrong height for an `UILabel` if I use `NSAttributedString` that has custom `kern` and `lineSpacing`.

Here is how I set the custom kern and line spacing:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let shortText = "Single line"
    self.label.attributedText = self.getAttributedText(text: shortText, kern: 0.2, lineSpacing: 8)
    self.label2.attributedText = self.getAttributedText(text: shortText, kern: 0, lineSpacing: 8)
}

private func getAttributedText(text: String, kern: CGFloat, lineSpacing: CGFloat) -> NSAttributedString {
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)

    let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    style.lineSpacing = lineSpacing

    let attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey : Any] =
        [.paragraphStyle : style,
         .kern: kern]

    attributedString.addAttributes(attributes,
                                   range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))

    return attributedString
}
```

And here is what I get:

[image: Result]

The first label (the one that has custom kern), has its height wrong. It's exactly 8 points taller than it should be - that's the custom line height that I am using.

This only happens for single line labels. If I use text that is on a couple of lines, it works as expected.

Comment: `.kern` seems to be misbehaving with other attirbutes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46172079/how-to-set-both-spacing-between-characters-and-strikethrough-style-for-uilabel

Comment: Good catch @MilanNosáľ

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug with `NSAttributedStringKey.kern`. As a workaround, you can calculate the number of lines of your `UILabel` with the suggestions [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28108745/3151675). If it has one line only, set `lineSpacing` to 0.

```
private func getAttributedText(text: String, kern: CGFloat, lineSpacing: CGFloat) -> NSAttributedString {
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)

    let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)

    let attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey : Any] = [.kern: kern,
                                                     .font: font]

    attributedString.addAttributes(attributes, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))

    let maxSize = CGSize(width: [custom width], height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    let sizeOfLabel = attributedString.boundingRect(with: maxSize, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)

    if sizeOfLabel.height > font.lineHeight {
        let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        style.lineSpacing = lineSpacing

        attributedString.addAttribute(.paragraphStyle, value: style, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))
    }

    return attributedString
}
```

Comment: This workaround might work most of the time. It has a performance penalty as you need to calculate the height of each UILabel at least twice.

In my case the initialization of that string happens long before the layout pass, which means I cannot easily pass the width of that UILabel.